# Details about implementation of CALL/RET instruction in QEMU (x86_64)

Tags: qemu

In file `target/i386/translate.c` the `CALL` instruction (opcode 0xe8) has this implementation:

```
    case 0xe8: /* call im */
    {
        if (dflag != MO_16) {
            tval = (int32_t)insn_get(env, s, MO_32);
        } else {
            tval = (int16_t)insn_get(env, s, MO_16);
        }
        next_eip = s->pc - s->cs_base;
        tval += next_eip;
        if (dflag == MO_16) {
            tval &= 0xffff;
        } else if (!CODE64(s)) {
            tval &= 0xffffffff;
        }
        tcg_gen_movi_tl(cpu_T0, next_eip);
        gen_push_v(s, cpu_T0);
        gen_bnd_jmp(s);
        gen_jmp(s, tval);
    }
    break;
```

The value in `next_eip` is saved by the following calls:

```
        tcg_gen_movi_tl(cpu_T0, next_eip);
        gen_push_v(s, cpu_T0);
```

But I can not find how this value (`next_eip`) is used in the `RET` implementation:

```
    case 0xc3: /* ret */
    ot = gen_pop_T0(s);
    gen_pop_update(s, ot);
    /* Note that gen_pop_T0 uses a zero-extending load.  */
    gen_op_jmp_v(cpu_T0);
    gen_bnd_jmp(s);
    gen_jr(s, cpu_T0);
    break;
```

While i trace `CALL` implementation i see code where return adress is used:

`void tcg_gen_op2(TCGOpcode opc, TCGArg a1, TCGArg a2)
{
    TCGOp *op = tcg_emit_op(opc); // INDEX_op_movi_i64
    op->args[0] = a1; // address of register
    op->args[1] = a2; // **REAL RETURN ADDRESS**
}`

But i can not find REAL RETURN ADDRESS while tracing `RET` implementation.

Can anyone tell me where exactly the `RET` instruction implementation uses the value in `next_eip`.

Answer (score 1):

The value in `next_eip` is popped from the stack:

```
ot = gen_pop_T0(s);
```

As a side-effect, this updates `cpu_T0` which is then used for the jump; see the implementation of `gen_pop_T0`:

```
TCGMemOp d_ot = mo_pushpop(s, s->dflag);

gen_lea_v_seg(s, mo_stacksize(s), cpu_regs[R_ESP], R_SS, -1);
gen_op_ld_v(s, d_ot, cpu_T0, cpu_A0);

return d_ot;
```

This is how `RET` retrieves the value which was pushed by `CALL`:

```
tcg_gen_movi_tl(cpu_T0, next_eip);
gen_push_v(s, cpu_T0);
```

When interpreting a `RET` instruction, the emulator can’t rely on internal knowledge: it has to behave exactly as the `RET` instruction does, retrieving its return address from the stack. (In real-world code, there are many cases of `RET`s following a `JMP` with a manually-set-up stack rather than a `CALL`, or a `CALL` never resulting in a `RET`, or code changing the return address for the `RET` by changing the value on the stack.) This is what QEMU’s `RET` implementation does: it pops the return address from the stack (`gen_pop_T0`) and processes that.